# Blender possible hidden animations?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

[Iron Man Model with mysterious green arrows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvQWH.png)

[Another mysterious green arrowed Iron Man](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1okg.png)

Aloha all!

I am really new to blender, and am working on a rigging for this Iron Man model for a unity project (generously created and shared here https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/67628
by user LucaScheller). I added my bones and heat maps but as I am starting to work on my animation, the green net arrows and lines keep getting my attention. Do these signify animations that are built in to the download? If so, how do I access and view them? If not, what are they for?

Thanks!

The Hidden Valkyrie

Answer (score 0):

The arrows and lines around the model represent bones in the armature. Instead of [displaying bones](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/armatures/properties/display.html) as octahedral or sticks you can assign a mesh object as a custom shape that will be [displayed in place of the bone](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/armatures/bones/properties/display.html).

The armature has a simple walk cycle animation and a [pose library](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/armatures/properties/pose_library.html) with a few different poses setup.

To play the walk cycle you will need to set it as the action for the rig, do that by selecting it in the [action editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/dope_sheet/action.html). You can also use the action in the [NLA editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/nla/tracks.html).

With the model containing over 420,000 vertices, I think you will find it too detailed to be used in a game. Also you will find more blender specific help at [blender.stackexchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thank you so much. I found the pose library and have the action editor. I agree that this one may be too detailed for what I am using it for, but given my newness to Blender, I just wanted a quick model to learn the basics. Thanks for the directions!